# Как извлечь объект из массива данных в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

При использовании Laravel столкнулся со следующей проблемой при использовании коллекции:

```
$products=DB::table(‘shop’)->get();
return $products->where(‘id’,$id)->title;
```

выдаёт ошибку, смысл которой в том, что  $products это массив, в котором элемент с ключом «1» объект, а не чистый объект и поэтому приходится обращаться так

```
return $products[1]->where(‘id’,$id)->title;
```

Но это неудобно и некрасиво. Предложите более эффективный способ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно так:

```
return $products->where('id', $id)->first()->title;
```

Comment: Точно!Спасибо. Не заметил метод first()  в коллекциях

Answer (score 2):

"Неудобно и некрасиво" - это использовать Eloquent без моделей. Поэтому писать надо так

```
return App\Shop::find($id)->title;
```

Предварительно создав модель Shop

Comment: Мне не нужно eloquent, я пользуюсь фасадом DB со всеми таблицами. Я создал сервиспровайдер, и в сервисконтейнере у меня уже загружены все данные из таблиц. Нужно только выдернуть запись из полученных коллекций